# Vivado: [XSIM 43-3294] Signal EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION received

Tags: simulation, xilinx, vivado

I'm getting the following error when I run the simulation.

```
ERROR: [Common 17-39] 'launch_simulation' failed due to earlier errors.
```

This project worked fine, but after reinstalling the same Vivado version, I keep getting errors when running the simulation. I have searched and searched several times and places, there are many who end up with this error, but got different suggestions. I honestly do not know what this error means.

The simulation referred me to the behav folder to open the elaborate log for more information about the error.

Here it is:

```
Vivado Simulator 2017.1
Copyright 1986-1999, 2001-2016 Xilinx, Inc. All Rights Reserved.
Running: C:/Xilinx2017v1/Vivado/2017.1/bin/unwrapped/win64.o/xelab.exe -wto 89ab4d8a8bd74d6d87079040762eb149 --debug typical --relax --mt 2 -L xil_defaultlib -L lib_cdc_v1_0_2 -L proc_sys_reset_v5_0_11 -L fit_timer_v2_0_8 -L secureip -L xpm --snapshot design_1_wrapper_behav xil_defaultlib.design_1_wrapper -log elaborate.log 
Using 2 slave threads.
Starting static elaboration
Completed static elaboration
Starting simulation data flow analysis
ERROR: [XSIM 43-3294] Signal EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION received.
```

What could the error 'Signal EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION received' mean?

Someone who have tips and advices?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using VHDL 2008 and trying to access a lower level signal in you test bench?

something like

```
alias CTL_empty is <<signal Inst_VMUX_Top.Inst_Switch_IF.CTL_empty : std_logic>>;
```

When I try to make decisions based on CTL_empty, my simulation fails